# How to increment element attribute by one without each loop?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to increment an attribute of an element by one **without** an "each loop".

Here below my input:

```
<div class="target" data="0"></div>
<div class="target" data="1"></div>
<div class="target" data="0"></div>
<div class="target" data="5"></div>
```

Here below the expected result

```
<div class="target" data="1"></div>
<div class="target" data="2"></div>
<div class="target" data="1"></div>
<div class="target" data="6"></div>
```

I tried the following but unfortunately without success:

```
$('.target').attr('data' + 1);
$('.target').attr('data', 1);
```

Comment: You're tries; the first one does not set the value, the second one I believe sets them all to 1.  You need to read and write to the same value...

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.each()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...one **without** an "each loop".

You can't, you'll need **some** kind of loop. `attr` will happily provide one:

```
$('.target').attr('data', function(_, v) {
// Note we want the *second* arg   ^^^^
    return Number(v) + 1;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$('.target').attr('data', function(_, v) {
    return Number(v) + 1;
});
// Show the values:
console.log("Values after update:");
$('.target').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("data"));
});
```

```html
<div class="target" data="0">....</div>
<div class="target" data="1">....</div>
<div class="target" data="0">....</div>
<div class="target" data="5">....</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: `data` is an invalid attribute for `div` elements. You can use a `data-` prefix, though: `<div data-value="0">`

Comment: *(If you don't see "Note we want the \*second\* arg" above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Thank you very much. This working great. What does the first argument stand for ?

Comment: @Marc: See [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), it's the index of the element in the set.